# Is it possible to access the indexes of a List using Java 8 Streams filter?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Is it possible to access the indexes of a List using Streams filter?
I mean... I know it is possible to do that with loops (while, for,etc.) but it is as if the List when it becomes a Stream loses the information about the indexes.

I think something like this:

```
list.stream().filter(x -> x > 100)
    .fiter(--getIndexOfEachValue--)
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

If I have List=[10,200,30,150,400,30]...

I expect result=[1,3,4]

Comment: please explain the input and output a bit.

Comment: Why do you need the indexes later. Perhaps it would help to think about the further computations you want to do on the collection. Perhaps you could integrate or append these into the collection-pipeline instead of refering later to the originial collection. btw. you can easily create a stream of pairs of index and value before doing the filter.

Comment: It seems there is no built-in `zipWithIndex` in Java (which may be an indication that there is usually a better way that does not need the index), so you have to do something like this: https://gist.github.com/danilomo/999c9d209e97218fe58c8a9042ca1261

Comment: @aschoerk In my original question I mentioned "List/map" .. I don't know Why Stefan Zobei change it .. yes I Know in a Map there is not a Index .. is a Key .. but I wanted to take advantage of speed in stream search and get the index/key ... as you know sometimes the keys are strings, also I'm exploring the possibilities with streams.

Comment: @JonathanMarin if you have a Map, this is easier, the `entrySet().stream()` will give you key/value pairs already, and you can filter on either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it is not possible.  The `stream()` call produces a stream of the values.  Since the values in a list are not unique, it is not possible to map them to a unique position in the original list.

---

You could code your example as:

```
list.stream().filter(x -> x > 100)
    .map(x -> list.indexOf(x))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

But bear in mind:

- this is not using the stream to get the element index: it is doing a lookup,
- as a result, it is an `O(N^2)` algorithm, and
- you will get unexpected results if the elements in `list` are not unique.

---

An alternative approach is to create a stream of the subscripts of the list.  Or simply iterate over the list.  Here is an example of the former:

```
IntStream.range(0, list.size())
     .filter(i -> list.get(i) > 100)
     .boxed()
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that we are streaming the indexes for the list rather than the list elements.  It will work if list elements are non-unique.